# Should small utility functions be split into header & source files or just add inline keyword?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, linker, inline, multiple-definition-error

I have some small utility functions (< 20 lines of code per function) that I am currently putting in a `utils.h` file with the keyword `inline` in front of them so I don't run into `multiple definition` linking errors. This is what I have always done for small functions.

I am wondering what the advantages and disadvantages are to:

1. Using my method
2. Putting the function declarations in `utils.h` and definitions in `utils.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantage of inline:

- If the header is included into many TU, the build time is slowed due to building of the function for each TU (this may be diminished if pre-built header is an option).
- When you make any change to the implementation, then all TU that include the header must be re-compiled. This is especially bad if the implementation changes often (bugs, new features, etc.) and when the header is used in many TU.
- If the implementation depends on any definition / declarations, then those dependencies transfer to all TU that include the header. This increases the time to build those TU and spreads the rebuilding caused by changes to the dependencies too. If the dependencies are system specific, then this complicates compatibility between systems.

Advantages of inline:

- If you reduce the number of TU; then build time from scratch improves.
- It allows inline expansion to the TU that include it (but that is also allowed by using link time optimisation).

Comment: Would you be able to add a part that contrasts inline with separating into header/source?

Comment: @24n8 That's what my answer contrasts.

Comment: This entire answer is about implementation in header vs separating into header/source. The `inline` keyword, despite its historical origins, no longer serves as an instruction for the compiler to perform inline expansion of a function call.

Comment: @NathanPierson Do you mean it "no longer serves ONLY as an instruction..." I thought it still serves, in part, as an instruction for the compiler to perform inline expansion of a function call?

Answer (score 1):

For header vs. source there is a HUGE speed difference for small functions here. Basically anything that the compiler would always inline is a good candidate to be in the header.

The potential gains inlineing gives you come at the cost of compile time. It can also be nice for debugging purposes to have an actual function that gets called in the binary where you can set a breakpoint.

Generally if the function it not called often then put it in the source file, it's just neater and nobody cares. Especially something with 20 lines excluding boiler plate. That's not really small. Only put stuff in the header that is time sensitive.

And do check out if your compiler can do LTO (link time optimization). Because with that you can have functions in the source and still get them inlined when you use LTO. But while developing you can compile without LTO and get quick builds (and slower binaries). So with LTO you can have your cake and eat it too.

Overall I would draw the line for functions in headers far lower than 20 lines. If your function only has a return statement then put it in the header, otherwise the source, and use LTO. That's my rule-of-thumb.

Comment: I will check regarding the LTO thing. The codebase I am working with is Pytorch. I would assume they would have all the optimal compilation/linkage optimizations available.

Comment: You would think so but it's still rare. LTO can really make the link time and memory requirements explode. So for larger projects Mr. Average Joe probably doesn't have the hardware to even do it. Years back I used it on freeciv. While I really had to wait for the link the game run 4 times as fast after. It's an extreme case because they had a bunch of getter functions in the source files instead of headers that get called billions of times.